# Spring Cloud @StreamListener consumer not registering CONSUMER-ID, HOST and CLIENT-ID in consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a spring cloud consumer to read message from one kafka topic. Following is the interface for channel

```java
    @Component
    public interface CollectionStreams {


       String INPUT_REPORT = "report-in";
       String OUTPUT_REPORT = "report-out";

       @Input(INPUT_REPORT)
       SubscribableChannel inboundReport();

       @Output(OUTPUT_REPORT)
       MessageChannel outboundReportToJM();
}
```

The problem we are facing is that while listing in the consumer group “report” we are not able to see CONSUMER-ID, HOST and CLIENT-ID as expected.

```
[root@innolx131112 templates]# kubectl -n tmo-ccm exec kafka-test-client -- /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe -group report
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
Consumer group 'report' has no active members.

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
report          3          2               3               1               -               -               -
report          1          4               4               0               -               -               -
report          2          1               1               0               -               -               -
report          4          2               2               0               -               -               -
report          0          2               2               0               -               -               -
```

By the way we are running our application as well as Kafka in Kubernetes.

Due to this issue we are not able to multiple POD of our application as all PODs

Following is the interface for channel

```java
@Component
public interface CollectionStreams {


   String INPUT_REPORT = "report-in";
   String OUTPUT_REPORT = "report-out";

   @Input(INPUT_REPORT)
   SubscribableChannel inboundReport();

   @Output(OUTPUT_REPORT)
   MessageChannel outboundReportToJM();
}
```

And we have define the method as follows to read message from topic.

```java
@StreamListener(CollectionStreams.INPUT_REPORT)
    //public void handleMessage(@Payload MessageT message) {
    public void handleMessage(@Payload MessageT message, @Headers MessageHeaders msg) {
```

Following is configuration yaml

**

```
cloud:
        stream:
          kafka:
            binder:
              brokers: kafka
              autoCreateTopics: false
            bindings:
              report-in:
                consumer:
                  autoCommitOffset: false
                  autoCommit: false
                  auto-offset-reset: earliest
                  autoCommitOnError: false
                  resetOffsets: false
                  autoRebalanceEnabled: false
                  ackEachRecord: false
          bindings:
            report-in:
              destination: report
              contentType: application/json
              group: report
              consumer:
                concurrency: 5
                partitioned: true
            report-out:
              destination: jobmanager
              contentType: application/json
              group: jobmanager
              producer:
                autoAddPartitions: true
```

**

---

We also have another consumer for which we have not set any kafka related consumer props and surprisingly those consumers are registering themselves properly.

Config:

```
cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          brokers: kafka
      bindings:
        parse-in:
          destination: parser
          contentType: application/json
          group: parser
          consumer:
            concurrency: 3
            partitioned: true
        parse-out:
          destination: jobmanager
          contentType: application/json
          group: jobmanager
          producer:
            partitionKeyExpression: headers['contentType']
            autoAddPartitions: true
```

And describe command output as below

```
[root@innolx131112 shyama]# kubectl -n tmo-ccm exec kafka-test-client -- /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe -group parser
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
parser          0          14              14              0               consumer-3-cb99e45e-21b3-4efb-ac7b-4f642a9486be /192.168.0.26   consumer-3
parser          1          13              13              0               consumer-3-cb99e45e-21b3-4efb-ac7b-4f642a9486be /192.168.0.26   consumer-3
parser          2          15              15              0               consumer-4-bec1e4af-d771-47fe-83ad-3440f3a6d4bd /192.168.0.26   consumer-4
parser          3          15              15              0               consumer-4-bec1e4af-d771-47fe-83ad-3440f3a6d4bd /192.168.0.26   consumer-4
parser          4          12              12              0               consumer-5-b9ac7e36-58cf-40cb-b37d-a0fa092a0d56 /192.168.0.26   consumer-5
```

Is it that as we are providing kafka related props for 1st consumer(report consumer), its not able to register???

Comment: Maybe you need to take this into account: `Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.` ?

Comment: That is referring to the old scala client. "Consumer group 'report' has no active members." simply means your app wasn't running when you entered the command. That info is transient and not retained when the app stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Consumer group 'report' has no active members.`

This simply means your app wasn't running when you entered the command.

That info is transient and not retained when the app stops.

The partitions might be assigned to a different instance next time.

**EDIT**

> whenever we are instantiating more consumers using same group they are processing the same old already processed by old consumers

Well, looking at your configuration more carefully, that's exactly what you asked for...

```
autoRebalanceEnabled: false
```

... means that Kafka will not use group management and the partitions will be allocated by Spring Cloud stream.

```
autoCommitOffset: false
```

means that Spring will not commit any offsets and that is the responsibility of your application. If you don't commit the offset, you will get the behavior you observe.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gary.

But the problem here is that our all consumers are in running state and consuming msg also. if you see we do not see that lag but consumers are not registering client id... SO, whenever we are instantiating more consumers using same group they are processing the same old already processed by old consumers msg which should not be.

Comment: That's due to how you have configured it - see the edit to my answer.